# Use NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey without crashing on iOS 5.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The check for availability seems to be working fine but I can't seem to set the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` key without getting this crash on launch:

> dyld: Symbol not found: _NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey Referenced from:
>   /Users/sam/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.0/Applications/B0872A19-3230-481C-B5CE-D4BDE264FBDF/Transit.app/Transit
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
>   in /Users/sam/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.0/Applications/B0872A19-3230-481C-B5CE-D4BDE264FBDF/Transit.app/Transit

Here's my method:

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL {    
    if (&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey == nil)
        return NO;

    NSError *error;
    [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];
    return (error != nil);
}
```

Crash goes away if I comment out this line:

```
[URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];
```

Do I have to weak-link Foundation?

EDIT: not sure if it makes a difference, but this method is put inside an `NSFileManager` category.

Comment: Are you sure that line isn't called? Can you step through with the debugger in iOS 5?

Comment: @kevboh the app crashes on launch, but the line is never actually called. Tried setting a breakpoint and it never gets called. The stack trace I get is http://cl.ly/ErTK

Comment: Very strange. Is your Base SDK 5.1? Maybe try deleting the app's derived data and cleaning?

Comment: Base SDK is 5.0. Deleted derived data and cleaned build folder, still no change :(

Comment: Ah, your Base SDK should be Latest (5.1).

Comment: @kevboh Sorry, Base SDK is 5.1, deployment target is 5.0.

Comment: @kevboh seems to be a bug specific to iPhone 5.0 Simulator since it runs fine on device. Should have done this test earlier. See my answer below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with the iPhone 5.0 Simulator. I tried running the code on a 5.0 device and no crash. Reported this bug as [rdar://11017158](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=1597401).

**EDIT**: this has been fixed in Xcode 4.5 DP2 (not sure if it is in 4.4).

Comment: Nice catch. I would #define out the code in the simulator so you can still test on it in 5.0.

Comment: I am afraid that the problem accure not only on simulator. I have the same crash when building Release build. Actually everything works fine on simulator. I think the problem is with const evaluation on application launch, because application crashed even before main method call.

Comment: I can confirm that it will actually crash on a 5.0.1 device when using a release build.

Answer (score 19):

Here's code for iOS <= 5.0.1 and >= 5.1 and includes the migration technique that @Cocoanetics mentioned.

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];
    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    if (&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey == nil) {
        // iOS 5.0.1 and lower
        u_int8_t attrValue = 1;
        int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
        return result == 0;
    } else {
        // First try and remove the extended attribute if it is present
        int result = getxattr(filePath, attrName, NULL, sizeof(u_int8_t), 0, 0);
        if (result != -1) {
            // The attribute exists, we need to remove it
            int removeResult = removexattr(filePath, attrName, 0);
            if (removeResult == 0) {
                NSLog(@"Removed extended attribute on file %@", URL);
            }
        }

        // Set the new key
        return [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Also this won't work for files that are present when a user upgrades from 5.0.1 to 5.1. Then these will be having the file attribute, but not the key. You'd have to check for this case and migrate the files. The safer approach would be to set both and use the actual NSString.

Comment: I forked the gist to add migration by detecting and removing the attribute: https://gist.github.com/2002382

Comment: You shouldn't use the presence of error to detect trouble; use the BOOL that setResourceValue:forKey:error returns. The Cocoa convention is that the error might have something in it (which you should ignore) on success.

Comment: @tim, I just suggested an edit that you can approve. Pretty much it handles the migration technique that Cocoanetics pointed out and it includes Jesse Rusak's fix for the NSError issue. I also am the one who committed ShareKit 2.0 to include the backup attribute code. Thanks to everyone's suggestions, I will update the code there in a future pull request.

Comment: Do not forget to #import <sys/xattr.h>.

Comment: Great. Thanks. So does this mean I still can save data into Documents folder if disable backup of my data?

Comment: This [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html) from iOS Developer Library might be of help.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line to force the symbol to be a weak import:

```
extern NSString * const NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey __attribute__((weak_import));
```

Comment: This does not solve the issue on a 5.0.1 device in my case. I still get a crash.

Comment: @Martin : I added it to the code file that references NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey.

Comment: Olivier : I never tested 5.0.1, I'll have to investigate that more.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're doing, this quick fix may work for you. It did for me.

Add the **CoreFoundation framework** to your project and mark it as **OPTIONAL** (not required).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this key is only present on 5.1 and above. For 5.0.1 you need to set the extended file attribute instead. The only backwards-compatible method would be to find out the NSString value of this key and set this instead below 5.1.

Comment: I'm not even looking for a backwards-compatible solution. I just want to set the attribute on iOS 5.1 and don't bother doing anything on 5.0 (that's what the check does). But even though that last line is never called, the app crashes with the "Symbol not found" error.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` is NOT weak-linked! I think if we find out the NSString value of NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey, it would work. But how to find it ??

Comment: Oh, so dumb i an... `NSLog(@"%@", NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey);` to find its value. So it gives `@"NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey"`, and by replacing `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` by `@"NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey"` it works !

Comment: Thanks to Cocoanetics, i posted a solution to the problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11647534/127493 It works for me, please keep me informed if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same thing after updating ShareKit and redoing a project to target iOS 5.1 I would either get an error at compilation or at linking related to NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey. 
The ShareKit people seem to recommend that you can solve the problem by making sure your project links with the CoreFoundation framework and set it to "Optional" rather than "Required". However this didn't work for me.

Eventually i got around it by using the preprocessor:

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    #ifndef NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey                   
    // iOS <= 5.0.1.
    const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];
    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;    
    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
    return result == 0;
    #else                                                                       
    // iOS >= 5.1
    // First try and remove the extended attribute if it is present
    int result = getxattr(filePath, attrName, NULL, sizeof(u_int8_t), 0, 0);
    if (result != -1) {
        // The attribute exists, we need to remove it
        int removeResult = removexattr(filePath, attrName, 0);
        if (removeResult == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Removed extended attribute on file %@", URL);
        }
    }
    return [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:nil];
    #endif
}
```

Comment: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey isn't a preprocessor macro, that #ifdef will always be false.