# How to implement Sharekit on xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone

Can anyone suggest me to how to implement ShareKit on xcode 4.2.Now i am trying to use
this Url https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit..but I got a lot of compilation error.I dont understad the first step they are desscribed.So please anyone help me to implement ShareKit on my application..

Comment: You might like to give us a bit more information (share the compilation errors, for example). (See what I did there - SHARE the compilation errors.... Get it? It's a question about Sharekit and I suggested he SHAREs the compilation errors.... Oh.... Never mind....)

Comment: @ Nick Bull..I got two eror it follows... Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 error..Use of undeclared identifier 'NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey'

Comment: Am getting stuck with step one

Comment: Step 1: Get ShareKit files (as Git submodule)

Comment: For Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 error, go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620651/use-nsurlisexcludedfrombackupkey-without-crashing-on-ios-5-0